# Object destructuring prevents typescript discrimination

Tags: typescript

I've been playing with typescript discrimination using tagged union types and I've run into something odd. If I switch on the actual object property everything works as expected. But if I use destructuring, typescript reports an error. I assume it has to do with how destructuring actually works when its compiled, but I don't know for certain. You can see this sample code on the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20discriminate%3A%20'FOO'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20details%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20discriminate%3A%20'BAR'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20numbers%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20FooOrBar%20%3D%20Foo%7CBar%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20foo%20%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20discriminate%3A%20'FOO'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20details%3A%20'Blah%20Blah%20Blah'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20breakTaggedUnionWithRest%20%3D%20(%7Bdiscriminate%2C%20...fooBar%7D%20%3A%20FooOrBar)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch(discriminate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'FOO'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(fooBar.details)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Foo2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20discriminate%3A%20'FOO2'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20details%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Bar2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20discriminate%3A%20'BAR2'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20details%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20FooOrBar2%20%3D%20Foo2%7CBar2%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20breakTaggedUnionWithoutRest%20%3D%20(%7Bdiscriminate%2C%20details%7D%20%3A%20FooOrBar2)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch(discriminate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'FOO2'%20%3A%20return%20details.toLowerCase()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20workingExample%20%3D%20(fooOrBar%3A%20FooOrBar)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch(fooOrBar.discriminate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'FOO'%3A%20return%20fooOrBar.details%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20workingExample2%20%3D%20(fooOrBar%3A%20FooOrBar2)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch(fooOrBar.discriminate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'FOO2'%3A%20return%20fooOrBar.details.toString%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

```
interface Foo {
  discriminate: 'FOO';
  details: string;
}

interface Bar {
  discriminate: 'BAR';
  numbers: number;
}

type FooOrBar = Foo|Bar;

const foo : Foo = {
  discriminate: 'FOO',
  details: 'Blah Blah Blah'
}

const breakTaggedUnionWithRest = ({discriminate, ...fooBar} : FooOrBar) => {
  switch(discriminate) {
    case 'FOO':
      console.log(fooBar.details);
      break;
  }
}

interface Foo2 {
  discriminate: 'FOO2';
  details: string;
}

interface Bar2 {
  discriminate: 'BAR2';
  details: number;
}

type FooOrBar2 = Foo2|Bar2;

const breakTaggedUnionWithoutRest = ({discriminate, details} : FooOrBar2) => {
  switch(discriminate) {
    case 'FOO2' : return details.toLowerCase();
  }
}

const workingExample = (fooOrBar: FooOrBar) => {
  switch(fooOrBar.discriminate) {
    case 'FOO': return fooOrBar.details;
  }
}

const workingExample2 = (fooOrBar: FooOrBar2) => {
  switch(fooOrBar.discriminate) {
    case 'FOO2': return fooOrBar.details.toString;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't destructure, the `switch`-`case` on the discriminator property allows TypeScript to narrow the type of the whole `fooOrBar` object and correctly deduce types of other properties on that object.  This is because TypeScript understands that you're trying to discriminate by a property of the object.

With destructuring, however, `discriminate` and other variables (`fooBar` in your first example and `details` in the second) become not related to each other. As a result, in the `case`s TypeScript doesn't deduce that the type of another variable may be narrowed, because the variable under `switch` and the variable you're trying to access are not related in any way at that point.